# Substitute variable in value of chpst loaded environment variable

Tags: bash, environment-variables, runit

If I use `chpst` to load environment variables like:

```
env BAR=baz chpst -e envdir mycommand
```

and in `envdir` I have a file `envdir/FOO` with contents

```
foo$BAR
```

is there a way so that for `mycommand` the value of `FOO` is `foobaz` instead of `foo$BAR`?

Obviously the above doesn't work; it leaves `FOO` set to `foo$BAR`. I'm wondering if there's something I can do to get substitution to happen on the values of the loaded environment variables.

---

Full context: mostly I have environment variables that are static once you pick the environment, but in some cases they need to be host specific. So in real life I have, for example, `HOST` set in the run environment with the appropriate hostname, and then I'd like to set something like `API_URL=http://$HOST:8080/`. I have this working without using `chpst`, but I'd like to use it to manage all my environment variables and it works perfectly in 90% of use cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this perhaps?  (assuming the contents of envdir are trustworthy)

put this file in envdir/run:

```
#!/bin/bash

for v in `dirname $0`/* ; do
    if [[ "`basename $v`" = run ]]; then
        continue;
    fi
    eval "export `basename $v`=`cat $v`"
done

exec "$@"
```

then:

```
./envdir/run some command
```

Comment: i decided not to do quite this but it set me on the right path: i already have run bash scripts that wrap each command so in those i've put the few things that need dynamic values. it's not a great general solution but it works well for my setup.